# How to get the CPU graphics usage?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, integrated-graphics

My CPU also provides graphics processing for my system.

It's easy to know the CPU's *core* usage separately by using a utility such as `top` (etc.), but how to get the CPU's *graphics* usage?

Comment: What CPU do you have?  Based on [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1541097) it be up to the driver to provide this capability.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310250/how-to-check-for-gpu-on-centos-linux) might also help.

Comment: I use Intel i5-4460, and I've solved this by the links you provided and the answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For NVIDIA graphics: see `nvidia-smi` [NVIDIA System Management Interface](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface)
- For Intel graphics: see `intel-gpu-tools` [Intel GPU tools for Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/precise/x11/intel-gpu-tools)